# Asynchronous Connection Download Callback

Tags: ios, xcode, asynchronous, callback, nsurlconnection

I created a class customDownload with the following methods:

```
-(NSString *) getTextFromLink: (PreliteRequest *) requestDetails
              asyncConnection: (BOOL) isAsync
               callbackMethod: (SEL) methodToExecute {

    mainRequest = requestDetails;

    NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    NSURLRequest *getRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] init];
    NSURLConnection *connection;

    NSURLResponse * response = nil;
    NSError * error = nil;

    if ([[requestDetails getType] isEqualToString:@"POST"]) {
        [postRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[requestDetails getUrl]]];
        [postRequest setHTTPMethod:[requestDetails getType]];
        [postRequest setValue:[requestDetails getPostLenght] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [postRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [postRequest setHTTPBody:[requestDetails getPostParameters]];

        if (isAsync) {
            tmpMethod = methodToExecute;
            connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];
        } else
            downloadedData = (NSMutableData *)[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    } else {
        getRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[requestDetails getUrl],[requestDetails getGetParameters]]]];
        if (isAsync) {
            tmpMethod = methodToExecute;
            connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:getRequest delegate:self];
        } else
            downloadedData = (NSMutableData *)[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:getRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    }

    NSString *result=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:downloadedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return result;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    downloadedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // Append the new data to the instance variable you declared
    [downloadedData appendData:data];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {


    return nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    NSString *tmpResult = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:downloadedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [self performSelector:tmpMethod withObject:tmpResult];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSLog(@"Connection error: %@",error);
}
```

In my view controller I declare the previous class and call the only method of that class getTextFromLink.

```
download = [[customDownload alloc] init];
[download getTextFromLink:request asyncConnection:YES callbackMethod:tmpSelector];
SEL tmpSelector = @selector(printResult:);
-(void) printResult:(NSString *) resultToPrint {
    NSLog(@"Risultato: %@",resultToPrint);
}
```

I pass to getTextFromLink the tmpSelector as parameter because that is the method I would like to call as soon the getTextFromDownloadLink has finished its job.
Actually getTextFromLink execute an asynchronous connection.

What I'm trying to do is to execute something when the asyncronous connection finished to download datas.
I would like to create a callback custom class to do this.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Unrelated to your question at hand, but I'd suggest changing that `PreliteRequest` to eliminate these `getType`, `getUrl`, etc., methods, and just define it to have `type`, `url` properties and use the standard getters for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than this selector model, generally people would use blocks for this. For example, define a `typedef` for your block:

```
typedef void(^PreliteRequestCompletionHandler)(NSString *string);
```

Since you're dealing with an asynchronous pattern, you might want to define a property which you can use to save this completion handler to call later:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) PreliteRequestCompletionHandler completionHandler;
```

You can then change that selector parameter to be a block parameter:

```
-(NSString *) getTextFromLink: (PreliteRequest *) requestDetails
              asyncConnection: (BOOL) isAsync
            completionHandler: (PreliteRequestCompletionHandler)completionHandler {

    self.completionHandler = completionHandler;

    // do stuff
}
```

And then, when you want to call that completion block, you do something like:

```
NSString *result = ...;

if (self.completionHandler) {
    self.completionHandler(result);
}
```

And then you can now use this new block parameter to your method:

```
download = [[customDownload alloc] init];
[download getTextFromLink:request asyncConnection:YES completionHandler:^(NSString *result) {
    NSLog(@"Risultato: %@", result);
}];
```

Comment: @prelite BTW, I used a single `NSString *` for the parameter to the completion handler because that's what your example used, but you might want two parameters, an `NSString` if successful, and an `NSError` if not (this is the pattern that Cocoa generally uses). Alternatively, you can use a separate failure handler block (which is a pattern that AFNetworking uses). Either works, but either way, you want your code that calls `getTextFromLink` to be able to detect and handle errors.

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much Rob... It wokerd perfectly...Since now I didn't know what blocks were you just opened a new world to me...thanks again...

Comment: Rob, can you explain why you have the "copy" qualifier for your PreliteRequestCompletionHandler. I was about to post a similar answer when I saw yours. I didn't use copy, and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: @rdelmar In [Working with Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html), Apple says "Note: You should specify `copy` as the property attribute, because a block needs to be copied to keep track of its captured state outside of the original scope. This isn’t something you need to worry about when using Automatic Reference Counting, as it will happen automatically, but it’s best practice for the property attribute to show the resultant behavior."

Comment: Using the completion handler all the code inside braces will be executed asynchronously in another thread...I tried it and it worked perfectly but if I would like to pass some parameters (I mean variables of the method which calls the asynch connection with completion handler) inside the completion handler how can I do without using singleton?

Comment: @prelite You can simply reference your calling routine's variables directly in the block. It's one of the advantages of the block pattern. (You might want to use the `weakSelf` pattern if you're concerned about strong reference cycles.) If this is unclear, I'd suggest you post your own question (add a link to it here, if you want).